# SQL - Get last 5 integer

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have two columns in two different tables. 
Column `PCTNo` has this value: `US2002014866` 
Column `pct_publishing_data` has this value: `JP1014866`
I want to get the last 5 value of `PCTNo` and the last 5 value of `pct_publishing_data` and if the 5 digits of `pct_publishing_data` are in `PCTNo` and the first 2 value are same then it will show up.. In this case it won't show up

This is the code that I have been implementing.

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd="", db="fak")
cursor = db.cursor()

#Execute SQL Statement:
cursor.execute("SELECT auip_wipo_sample.PCTNo FROM auip_wipo_sample INNER JOIN us_pat_2005_to_2012 ON RIGHT(auip_wipo_sample.PCTNo,5) = RIGHT(us_pat_2005_to_2012.pct_publishing_data,5) AND LEFT(auip_wipo_sample.PCTNo,2) = LEFT(us_pat_2005_to_2012.pct_publishing_data,2)")
#Get the result set as a tuple:
result = cursor.fetchall()

#Iterate through results and print:
for record in result:
    print record
print "Finish."

#Finish dealing with the database and close it
db.commit()
db.close()
```

But it doesn't work, it gives me all of them

Help.

Comment: You're getting all?!?  The inner join in the SQL should never work because 6 characters will never match 5 characters...  014866 != 14866 unless the DB is casting them to numeric...

Comment: OhI am sorry, I have edited the questions. It can be 5 characters. I get the last 5 character to be matched and shown perfectly, but i can't get the first two character to match. Am I correct to use `AND` there?

Comment: Would you mind to edit the question itself (the title) also, please?

Comment: I am so sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work fine, you can use `AND`  because you want to show them only if the right end and left end matches. But of course `US2002014866` does not match `JP1014866` because to match it should be `US1014866`.

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8fb2/2) that does it (I simplified the table and column names)

```
create table table1 (x1 varchar(20), y1 varchar(20)); 
create table table2 (x2 varchar(20), y2 varchar(20)); 
insert into table1 values ('US2002014866','foo1');
insert into table2 values ('US1014866','foo2');
insert into table2 values ('JP1014866','bar');

select *
from   table1
join   table2 on ( left(x1,2)= left(x2,2) and 
                  right(x1,5)=right(x2,5) )
```

Result is only one row:

```
X1           Y1   X2        Y2
US2002014866 foo1 US1014866 foo2
```

Comment: Yeah, I am now processing the python script, it takes soo long because it has like 700k rows. :( anyway, what if there are country like `SGD` should I change the `LEFT(auip_wipo_sample.PCTNo,3)` instead of 2? because some country has 3 characters... right?

Comment: That will make a more complicated condition and leaves you some challenge and work with boolean algebra (dealing with `AND` and `OR`) :-). Regarding the long run time you might want to add an index on PCTNo and pct_publishing_data. Google how to do that. I am not sure about mySQL's ability to handle substrings in indicies. But that is worth a new question.

Comment: I have added an index on PCTNo. THis is how I did that `ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME ADD INDEX (COLUMN_NAME)` Is that correct?

Comment: I do not know about that syntax. I use `CREATE INDEX my_idx_name ON my_table_name (my_column_name)`

Comment: Can I use the code like this? `SUBSTR(auip_wipo_sample.PCTNo,7,5) LIKE ('%RIGHT(us_pat_2005_to_2012.pct_publishing_data,5)%')`